# More control over regression trees in R

Tags: r, tree, regression, rpart

I want to have more control over my regression tree than what the R package rpart allows. Does anyone know if there's a package in R which allow me to specify the following:

1. The number of splits allowed at each node (so far it seems I can only have 2 splits)
2. The maximum depth of the tee
3. The first n splits
4. The minimum number of dollars (as opposed to observations) a leaf must have in order to be a candidate for a further split.

Comment: (1) Most tree implementations you will find are recursive binary partitioning, with an emphasis on the "binary". I think **partyKit** implements multiway splits for some types of variables. There may be other packages... (2) rpart already does this (3) Very unlikely, unless you write your own partitioning code, (4) Huh? This reads as nonsense to me. Dollars? Do your trees get an allowance?

Comment: Thanks-partyKit helped with the multiway splits. Clarification on #4: I'm working with insurance data and I want to be able to control the amount of premium in a node as opposed to the number of policies (observations). I'd like to specify each node should have no less than a total of, say, $500,000 in premium before attempting to make another split.  I don't care if it's one $500k policy or several smaller policies whose premium adds to $500k.